# Python multiprocessing: Updating objects in nested for loop (itertools.product)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools, nested-for-loop

I have a question regarding the multiprocessing of objects. I'm not sure if just my syntax isn't right or if I'm completely in the wrong direction with this one.

Let's say I have a class with some defined methods:

```
class Body:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def update(self, other):
        self.x += other.y

    def update2(self):
        self.x += 1
```

Now I have a routine that creates the objects and loop through them to update them. I use itertools.product (as I want to add a value of every object to another value of one object). 'bodies' is a list of the created objects

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self, bodies):
    self.bodies = bodies

         for body,_body in itertools.product(self.bodies,self.bodies):
             body.update(_body)
```

Everything works fine and I get the right results. Now I would like to multiprocess this for loop. I've already done so with another loop in the file but can't get this to work. And after hours of trying I'm to sure what to do. Or if it's a completely wrong approach.

I'm using concurrent.futures and create

```
 self.p = cf.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

in the Calc class

A working function I have is:

```
for result in self.p.map(Body.update2, self.bodies):
        pass
```

My ideas so far have led me to:

```
for result in self.p.map(lambda body, _body: Body.update(body,_body), self.bodies, self.bodies):
       pass
```

Or some variants of that. I get no error messages but the answers are clearly wrong. The non multiprocess version of map() has the same result. So I guess the bug lies somewhere in a wrong syntax. But yet I get no errors..

I hope I worded my question not that bad. It's my first question here and english is not my native language.

So again: Can't I use the map() function the way I intended to? Is there another function that's more suitable? Or do I have to take another approach to calculating everything "outside" of the objects themself?

Thanks if you have taken the time to read until here. Any help or direction where to look is appreciated.

Have a good day.

Edit:

Ok, I got the map function to work. I wanted to convert this function:

```
 for body,_body in itertools.product(self.bodies,self.bodies):
         body.update(_body)
```

My solution that works well is:

```
 for body in self.bodies:
     for result in map(lambda _body:Body.update(body,_body), bodies):
```

So as I already guessed my use of the lamda function wasn't quite right.
But now I have the problem, if I understand it correct that objects can't be updated in that way in a multi process serialization so I have to rewrite the code a bit.

Comment: You say you want to use multiprocessing, but in your code you are using threading. Also, if you think the error is in `Body.update` functions, then why don't you share the relevant code here.

Comment: I thought the ThreadPoolExecutor from the conncurent.futures library is the Standard for multiprocessing. Isn't that so? And I don't know what you mean with Body.update? It's right there. And the function itself is not a problem as it works perfect in a non multiprocess routine

Comment: My bad, I didn't see that you had already defined it. As for your first question, `ThreadPoolExecutor`, as the name suggests, uses threading. To use multiprocessing you need to use `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Note that `multiprocessing != multithreading`

Comment: Hey, yes that was an error on my end while copying. I got the right results now using the whole map, lambda thing in a slightly different way. I will post my solution once I figured out everything. But of course there is a new problem. My situation now is:
I get the map() function to work properly, but the MultiProcessExecutor says that it's unable to pickle my objects. I guess I still have to dig through some documentation. Thank you very much for the nice exchange.